# Is there any way to force showing ask permission in chrome?

Tags: jquery, browser, permissions, webcam, webcam.js

I don't know if this is  code issue or browser issue.

Currently i'm using webcam.js to my web for showing camera.

But when i open the page url. It shows error because the camera is not allowed.

But why it's not showing permission before?

When i check the permissions, it set to "ask(default)" but why there's no popup about asking permission ?

How to solve this issue ?

**Edit**
using below code already

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following setting?

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: { facingMode: "environment" },
  });
```

However, Android chrome may face permission issue in alert and you probably fix it by following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsNZnTFu0r8

Hopefully, it is helpful.